# how to remove the border between the window title and content

Tags: wpf, window, styles, border

I have create a Window with Ribbons (2010 - `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`).

It looks like that:

[image]

Now, is there a border over the tabs (between the tabs and the title). This is very ugly.

It should looks like Microsoft Office Word:

[image]

What can I do, that there is no border between the tabs and the titlebar?

(The RibbonWindow is used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use now the [Fluent Ribbon](http://fluent.codeplex.com), that solve the problem.

Comment: Posting your own answer is acceptable. But, accepting it? I don't see how your answer is more correct than John's.

Comment: @Robin_Maben, I've already used the RibbonWindow all the time. And the border was still there.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you're using the standard WPF Window. Try using the Ribbon framework's [RibbonWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonwindow%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) instead. It integrates the Ribbon into the window itself rather than just containing it like a normal control, which is what Window does.